# Как использовать интервалы

Tags: c#, winforms

Надо сделать интервал из которого программа будет сама задавать значение
и потом чтобы при проверке если не подошло значение ,то программа возвращалась в начало и изменило значение на другое и не использовала прошлое
и как можно сделать процентное соотношение типа 
T приблизительно = T1
1000 = 1012 
типа разница в 1.2 процента

заранее спасибо если не понятно написал напишите я попробую переформулировать вопрос заранее спасибо

> Что за смысл у интервала? Это действительно некоторый фиксированный
>   enum с определёнными значениями или это значение типа "напряжение
>   сети", в котором допускаются вещественные числа от 110 до 220 с любым
>   шагом?

интервал коэффициентов для расчета на примере 0.8-1.15 и шаг 0.01

Comment: напишите лучше в виде последовательности действий типо нумерованного списка. 1. - сделать то, то 2. сделать другое. Чтото в этом роде

Comment: @AK  интервал коэффициентов для расчета на примере 0.8-1.15 и шаг 0.01

Comment: @AK спасибо. А на счёт приблизительного равенства не знак как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> интервал коэффициентов для расчета на примере 0.8-1.15 и шаг 0.01

В вашем случае вам вероятно проще всего будет использовать массив. Конструировать можно в цикле, можно через linq.

```
private double[] InitKf(int from, int to, double step)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(from, to - from + 1).Select(x => step * x).ToArray();
}
```

Ну и используйте:

```
double[] kf = this.InitKf(8, 15, 0.01);
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> А насчёт приблизительного равенства не знаю как

Попаданием в интервал:

```
if(this.ApproxEqual(14, 15, 2))
{
    Console.WriteLine("14 попадает в интервал 15±2");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("14 не попадает в интервал 15±2");
}
```

Где

```
private bool ApproxEqual(double testedValue, double baseVal, double delta)
{
    if(testedValue < baseVal + delta && testedValue > baseVal - delta)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Также если хотите можете задавать delta в процентах, формула изменится незначительно.